# How to build mongo-tools deb package from source?

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to rebuild mongo-tools deb package from source. Basically I want to build a package like: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/jessie/mongodb-org/3.6/main/binary-amd64/

But when I checked out the repo: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools, I couldn't find anything there to use. Please help me figure out a way to build this package.

TIA.

Comment: Far too broad. Why do you think you need to build this anyway? And last I checked, all tools had been rewritten in Go. There is of course [instructions](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools#building-tools). Maybe you should follow them, and if you have a specific problem then you can post a question with those specific details.

Comment: Hi, I am just adding some custom stuff and testing it by making a deb package. The only problem is I have a hard dependency to use the deb package. I am able to do the go build. I am just looking for a way where I can package it in deb.

Comment: The Debian packaging for MongoDB server tools is managed as part of the server distribution. You can find the server's packaging config in [github.com/mongodb/mongo/debian](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/debian), but it would likely be much easier to create your own package via `dpkg-deb`. For example: [Building a Simple Deb Package](http://www.hackgnar.com/2016/01/simple-deb-package-creation.html).